# Using Vite and React, "FIRESTORE (9.20.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state" occurs when deployed on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vite, vercel

I am using Vite with React, as well as firebase and react-router-dom. Everything works fine when using `npm run dev`. However, when I deploy my project to Vercel, the following error occurs when I try to **get/upload *any data*** from/to firestore:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.20.0): FIRESTORE (9.20.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.20.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: undefined
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

I have tried pretty much anything at this point, I've tried removing every async part of my firestore code, I've tried making every firestore code I have async, but none worked and the error remains.
I have also tried to indicate vercel to build with Vite in development mode (`vite build --mode development`)
I do have to point out though that I have tried making an MCVE using only React and not Vite and the error did not occur.